# Laravel multi-auth Auth::guest() scope

Tags: php, laravel-5

I use https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth to authentication in my project. When I log in I will redirect to student/home page and there I can see this part of navbar:

```
@else
    <li>
        <a href="{{ url('/'.config('auth.defaults.guard').'/logout') }}"
           onclick="event.preventDefault();
           document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
            Wyloguj <i>{{ Auth::user()->name}} {{ Auth::user()->surname }}
                @if(Auth::user()->index)
                    ({{ Auth::user()->index }})
                @endif</i>
        </a>
```

but when I go to home page, or testView or somewhere else I can't see this part, only as if I was not logged in. I don't know how to fix it.

Navbar

```
<nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="/testView">Test View</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="/search">Szukaj</a></li>
        {{-- <li role="presentation"><a href="/student/register">Register</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="/login">Login</a></li> --}}

        @if (Auth::guest())
            <li>
                <a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{{ url('/student/register') }}">Register</a>
            </li>
        @else
            <li>
                <a href="{{ url('/'.config('auth.defaults.guard').'/logout') }}"
                   onclick="event.preventDefault();
                   document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">

                    Wyloguj <i>{{ Auth::user()->name}} {{ Auth::user()->surname }}
                        @if(Auth::user()->index)
                            ({{ Auth::user()->index }})
                        @endif</i>
                </a>

                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/'.config('auth.defaults.guard').'/logout') }}" method="POST"
                      style="display: none;">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                </form>
            </li>
        @endif

    </ul>
</nav>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
})->name('home');

Route::get('/testView', function(){
    return view('forms.rateThesis');
});

Route::get('/contact', function(){
    return view('forms.contact');
});

Route::get('/login', function(){
    return view('layouts.loginLinks');
});

Route::get('/showUsers/{table}', 'SearchController@showUsers');
Route::get('/search', 'SearchController@showSearch');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'student'], function () {
    Route::get('/login', 'StudentAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login', 'StudentAuth\LoginController@login');
    Route::post('/logout', 'StudentAuth\LoginController@logout');

    Route::get('/register', 'StudentAuth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('/register', 'StudentAuth\RegisterController@register');

    Route::post('/password/email', 'StudentAuth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    Route::post('/password/reset', 'StudentAuth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
    Route::get('/password/reset', 'StudentAuth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
    Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'StudentAuth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
});
```

Sorry for my terrible English

Comment: I guess that your auth session works only within `Route::group(['prefix' => 'student'], function () {` scope, as you had two areas

Comment: I tried this way but it still doesn't work. I think it is connected with session.

Comment: This is my repo https://github.com/dominik04u/system 
Could someone told me what is wrong?